# Android 13 - request notification permission

Tags: android, kotlin

I've added this inside manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

besides other permissions above `<application`

And i'm using the code provided in gogole docs:

```
private val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
) { isGranted: Boolean ->
    if (isGranted) {
        // FCM SDK (and your app) can post notifications.
    } else {
        // TODO: Inform user that that your app will not show notifications.
    }
}

private fun askNotificationPermission() {
    // This is only necessary for API level >= 33 (TIRAMISU)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // FCM SDK (and your app) can post notifications.
        } else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)) {
            // TODO: display an educational UI explaining to the user the features that will be enabled
            //       by them granting the POST_NOTIFICATION permission. This UI should provide the user
            //       "OK" and "No thanks" buttons. If the user selects "OK," directly request the permission.
            //       If the user selects "No thanks," allow the user to continue without notifications.
        } else {
            // Directly ask for the permission
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
        }
    }
}
```

but `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` is red and when I do alt + enter it doesn't work

Comment: Raise your `compileSdk` or `compileSdkVersion` to 33 in your module's `build.gradle`.

Comment: Already was.. :(

Comment: Then I am rather confident that [`import android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS` will work](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission?hl=en#POST_NOTIFICATIONS). For example, I just created a scrap project using Android Studio Electric Eel, added that `import`, and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your compileSdk is 33 and if it's still not working do invalidate catches and rest

Comment: Already was 33 and deleting cache and restart doesn't help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, fixed by importing android.Manifest, not android.Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
so just add :

```
import android.Manifest
```